# javascript set cookie doesn't work on chrome android

Tags: javascript, android, google-chrome, cookies

i have a problem to set a cookie on chrome on my android phone.
The source code is upload on an online server.
here my javascript code :

```
    function updateCookie( value ) {
        document.cookie = 'l='+value+'; expires=Thu, 2 Aug 240 20:47:11 UTC; path=/';
        location.reload();
    }
```

it work on chrome/mozilla on my computer
it work on mozilla on my android phone
but it doesen't work on chrome on my android phone

Can sommeone have an issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem : the date was invalid.
I modify my function to this

```
    function updateCookie( langue ) {
        // today + 1 year
        var exdate = new Date().getTime() + (1000*60*60*24*7*52);
        var date_cookie = new Date(exdate).toUTCString();
        document.cookie = 'l='+value+'; expires='+date_cookie+'; path=/';
        location.reload();
    }
```

And that work on chrome/mozilla on computer and android

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that on a website with https and SameSite="None", cookies were not getting set.  When I added the "secure" attribute, it worked:

```
var is_ssl = window.location.protocol === "https:";

var ss = is_ssl ? ";SameSite=None" : ";SameSite=Lax";
var sec = is_ssl ? ";secure" : "";

document.cookie = name + " = " + value + ss + sec;
```